# Importing fields from a SharePoint list to an InfoPath form

Tags: list, infopath

As the title says I'm trying to important fields from a SP 2010 list to a InfoPath form. I thought it would be a simple matter of going to Data and using the 'From SharePoint' option and pointing it at the list, but nothing happens. Am I doing something wrong or is there another option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the right part of the screen you see a dropdown list. If it says `Main`, click on the arrow and select your list. You will see your fields.